# OnClick on child div should not trigger parent div's onClick method for a particular child

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Consider the following React component

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={() => console.log("on app div")}>
      <div className="first" onClick={() => console.log("first div")}>
        first
      </div>
      <div className="second" onClick={() => console.log("second div")}>
        second
      </div>
      <div className="third">third</div>
    </div>
  );
```

}

So, a click on child div's will currently trigger onClick methods of both parent and child div's. But for the first child I would like only child onClick method to be triggered. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried giving the child div a higher z-index value but it's still triggering both onClicks, here is the css I've tried

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.first,.second,.third {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.first {
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.second {
  background: lightcoral;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}

.third {
  background: lawngreen;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
```

Could anyone please tell if there is anything wrong with the css I've tried or any other method in order to achieve this.

Comment: e.preventdefault is your frind here.

Comment: Event.preventDefault() and or event.stopPropagation() might help here inside the click functions

Comment: @AtulRajput could you say on which div I've to add e.preventDefault

Comment: from where you don't want your event to bubble to its parent, Ie. your child element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use event.stopPropagation()

```
<div className="second" onClick={(event) =>
    event.stopPropagation()
    console.log("second div")
 }>
    second
</div>
```

Comment: It worked thanks, could you also tell if the approach I tried with z-index makes any sense here, i.e isn't z-index supposed to work that way?

Comment: Z-index approach for this is not right, By z-index, you can only manage the click of 2 sibling elements, but anyhow the event bubbling will occur, and it will go to the parent, so if you ever want to achieve this, z-index won't help, only the given solution will.

Comment: it can work for you but it can have side effects on styles and as per documents e.stopPrppagation() is a recomended way